# HTTP2 en Nginx como proxy (proxy_pass+upstream)

Tags: nginx, proxy

Tengo varios servidores de Nginx que hacen de proxy para otros servidores a la vez que convierten la conexión en HTTPS. El problema es que la conexión entre esos servidores y el cliente se realizan a través de http/1.1 y por más que miro y pruebo no soy capaz de hacer que sea HTTP2.

La conexión entre el servidor de proxy y el Backend es a través de HTTP y no tiene límite de conexiones (además de ser rápida), por lo que en este caso no me preocupa que no sea HTTP2 (además de que el Nginx he leído que no lo soporta).

La configuración que uso es la misma que estoy utilizando en otros servidores que sirven los ficheros desde local en lugar de ser proxy y funciona correctamente, y he estado buscando en google a ver si encontraba algo y no he sido capaz.

Esta es mi configuración:

```
upstream 00_httpS_proxy {

    server 192.168.0.25:80 ;
}

server {
    server_name _;
    listen *:443 http2 ssl;

  # HTTPS
  ssl_certificate     /server/keys/cert.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /server/keys/cert.key;

  ssl on;
  ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
  ssl_session_timeout  10m;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128:AES256:AES:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!3DES';
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  ssl_stapling off;
  ssl_stapling_verify off;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://00_httpS_proxy;
        proxy_connect_timeout   30s;
        proxy_send_timeout      30s;
        proxy_read_timeout      30s;
        send_timeout            30s;

        proxy_http_version      1.1;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
    }
}
```

¿Alguien sabe algo de esto?

Un saludo y muchas gracias.

Comment: por si te sirve aun lo ocupas https://github.com/areliszxz/grpcs-grpc-nginx-grpcs_go-grpcs_node-grpcs_java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final el problema es la versión de openssl. Nginx pide la versión 1.0.2 como mínimo para usar http2, y Debian 8 utiliza la versión 1.0.1.
Descargue la 1.0.2 de jessie-backports y nginx la usaba, pero al estar compilado con la 1.0.1 seguía sin funcionar. Upgradeando el SO a Debian 9 se soluciona el problema, ya que esta versión usa openssl 1.1.0.

Un saludo